# NGINX / Location with regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I wish that every request in the following format: `/files/(whatever..)/(1 or 2 or 3)` will go to the `files_1` upstream with the `/(whatevet)` command.  If the url is in the following format `/files/(whatever..)/(4 or 5 or 6)`, it will go to the `files_2` upstream with the `/(whatevet)` command.

Here is my location file:

```
location ~ "^/files/(.*)/[123]/" {
        rewrite ^/files/(.*)/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://files_1 ;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
}

location ~ "^/files/(.*)/[456]/" {
        rewrite ^/files/(.*)/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://files_2 ;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
}
```

When I check the logs, It doesn't do the redirection with the command `/files/save/2/` (which should go to `files_1` upstream with the command: `/save`)

How can I do it?

Comment: Your `location` regex *requires* a trailing `/` after the final numeric element. So `/files/save/2` does not match any of the above location blocks. Also, your `rewrite` regex is not guaranteed to pick out only the `save` for the `$1`.

Comment: @RichardSmith:  its /files/save/2/. I will update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>It's possible that you have another `location /` block that is redirecting `/files/save/2` to `/files/save/2/` because the former does not match your current location blocks.</del>

You could eliminate the captures on the `rewrite` by using a named capture in the `location` regex, like this:

```
location ~ "^/files(?<command>.+)/[123]/" {
    rewrite ^ $command break;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, correct the `rewrite` directive so that only the command is extracted:

```
rewrite ^/files(.+)/\d/ $1 break;
```

or:

```
rewrite ^/files/([^/]+)/ /$1 break;
```

Comment: I try your suggestion, so I did:
`location ~ "^/files/(.*)/[123]/" {
        rewrite ^/files(.+)/\d/ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://files_1 ;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
}

location ~ "^/files/(.*)/[456]/" {
        rewrite ^/files(.+)/\d/ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://files_2 ;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
}` and it still doesn't work for me. It send the all command

Comment: location ~ "^/files(?<command>.+)/[123]/" {
    rewrite ^ $command break;
    ...
}
Also this suggestion doesn't work. I get 404. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I have tested both approaches and I cannot make either fail. I did correct an error in the third one. Are you sure that `nginx` is being restarted?